# What is faster. Querying many small tables or big table

Tags: database, database-design

What's generally faster in programming with databases: querying many small tables, or is it better to have a big table?

Comment: and what? Probably it is better to query a reasonably large table insteand of many small tables , which are also harder to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the size of a table as such should be your criteria... modern relational databases can pull one row out of millions of rows very quickly - that's really not a concern.

What you should do however is design your tables in such a way that they **make sense**, e.g. contain **one entity** and only one entity. Don't start mixing multiple entities into a single table...

Like classes in your C# application, a database table should always be dealing with one **responsibility (or concern)** only. Don't store disparate data into a single data - just for the sake of a perceived performance benefit.....

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an objective answer to your question, unless you do not explain the problem (database/langauge) a little more, the decision could be based on a multiple scenarios.

I will like to answer the Y before X.

If the records are of "Same" type, it is not advised to split it into multiple tables.

If the records could be of different type. spliting it into Tables [ Database normalization ] is highly recommended as the larger table will contain null records and hog space.

Coming back to your problem,

If you fragment it too much, the Foreign Key lookups might effect performance. So there is a sweet spot.

Also, if the Join of data is happening at application level in languages like python etc, the data concatenation can be slower compared if it was done in the Database itself. Most advanced relational databases, support Nested Loops. to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In general, with all else being equal, querying one table is faster than querying many tables, to get the same data.

Joins are expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is against the Normalization rules, but nowadays in PCs world, **memory is cheap but speed is costly**, so if we have a slow performance PC and a big Database to run in it, It is better to break the Normalization Rule and having extra fields in a table so that we don't be forced to make a join with another table.
suppose we have 3 related Tables with ( One - Many ) relationships Like [table_Customers] 1 --> Many [table_Orders]  1 --> Many [table_Order_Items], so by putting an extra [Customer_id] field into the [table_order_Items] we don't need a join, its all within one single big table, indeed that is a waste of Memory but a big push to speed and performance when a slow PC is being used.